# Add an email address as a shortcut in Android phone

Tags: keyboard, email, lg-g2, dictionary, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using an LG G2 phone with the standard keyboard. I wanted to add a shortcut or entry to the personal dictionary so that I wouldn't have to type out my email address all the time.

However it is not possible to enter the "@" symbol in the shortcut or personal dictionary dialog. I have save the components of my address to the dictionary but it enters with spaces which defeat any time saving as I need to remove them.

Is there another technique to achieve this? It seems like I need to install a third party keyboard app, but this sounds extreme for such a commonplace issue.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to use another keyboard then. Even android's stock keyboard allows email addresses in it's dictionary.